# Красота чи краса?

Tags: вибір-слова, різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Цікаво якому з слів "[краса](http://sum.in.ua/s/krasa)" та "[красота](http://sum.in.ua/s/krasota)" потрібно надавати перевагу? Як бачите обидва слова є в СУМ-11, але цікаво, що вже в СУМ-20 слово "[красота](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44856&page=1420)" має примітку "розм." А взагалі мене ще цікавить чи не є це запозиченням від російського "красота".

На Вікіпедії є сторінки "[Красота](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)" та "[Краса](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0)". Однак, як бачимо, в другій статті набагато більше інформації, а слово "красота" взагалі не зустрічається. [Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0) пише, що ці два слова синоніми - причому коло слова "красота" знову ж немє жодних приміток. Також результати Гуглу дають таку статистику:

Слово "Краса" - 14 400 000 (більшість сайтів справді українські і статті на них написані українською мовою)

Слово "Красота" - 374 000 000 (однак, незважаючи на фільтр "Показувати результати лише українською", одразу ж бачимо, що на першій мові зустрічаються статті російською мовою - "Женская красота 2019: тенденции красоты и стиля", "Красота: уход, макияж, маникюр , прически. Секреты красоты и ..." тощо).

Comment: Дякую за запитання. Теж цікавить відповідь та пояснення.